# Listen for Changes In Cassandra Datastore?

Tags: java, cassandra

I wonder if it is possible to add a listener to Cassandra getting the table and the primary key for changed entries? It would be great to have such a mechanism.

Checking Cassandra documentation I only find adding StateListener(s) to the Cluster instance.

Does anyone know how to do this without hacking Cassandras data store or encapsulate the driver and do something on my own?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this future jira --
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8844

If you like it vote for it : )

#### CDC

> "In databases, change data capture (CDC) is a set of software design
> patterns used to determine (and track) the data that has changed so
> that action can be taken using the changed data. Also, Change data
> capture (CDC) is an approach to data integration that is based on the
> identification, capture and delivery of the changes made to enterprise
> data sources."
> -Wikipedia
>
> As Cassandra is increasingly being used as the Source of Record (SoR)
> for mission critical data in large enterprises, it is increasingly
> being called upon to act as the central hub of traffic and data flow
> to other systems. In order to try to address the general need, we,
> propose implementing a simple data logging mechanism to enable
> per-table CDC patterns.

Comment: I voted for the issue and also purposed another way to implement this listener capability.

Answer (score 2):

If clients need to know about changes, the world has mostly gone to the message broker model-- a middleman which connects producers and consumers of arbitrary data.  You can read about Kafka, RabbitMQ, and NATS [here](https://seroter.wordpress.com/2016/05/16/modern-open-source-messaging-apache-kafka-rabbitmq-and-nats-in-action/).  There is an older DZone article [here](https://dzone.com/articles/exploring-message-brokers).  In your case, the client writing to the database would also send out a change message.  What's nice about this model is you can then pull whatever you need from the database.

Kafka is interesting because it can also store data.  In some cases, you might be able to dispose of the database altogether.

Comment: I'm not certain this answer really solves the problem. While a message broker does distribute events, writing to it directly from server code in tandem with Cassandra can be dangerous, since distributing a transaction between two data stores (Cassandra and the broker) requires either a two-phase commit with timeout or the [transactional outbox pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html). Unless you can accept at-most-once delivery, CDC (see phact's answer) can be used with one of the above listed technologies to implement at-least-once delivery.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like triggers?

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/tree/trunk/examples/triggers

> A database trigger is procedural code that is automatically executed
>   in response to certain events on a particular table or view in a
>   database. The trigger is mostly used for maintaining the integrity of
>   the information on the database. For example, when a new record
>   (representing a new worker) is added to the employees table, new
>   records should also be created in the tables of the taxes, vacations
>   and salaries.

Comment: Can the trigger report back to a client? on a cluster object I can register for cluster wide events but only for its topology.

Comment: Personally i do not have that much experience with cassandra only  remember in 2.0 that triggers where being introduced from a Reddit post so i cant really help you with the details sorry.